# What does Java EE compliant means?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, terminology, application-server

We often say that the particular application server is a Java EE compliant server. But I am still not completely aware of what it means exactly. Need more information on this.

Answer (score 5):

It means that it passes the Java EE Technology Compatibility Kit.

Sun (now Oracle) created the specification for Java EE (previously called J2EE) along with a large test suite checking that the application server behaves as the specification requires.  This is a non-trivial test to pass, but means that if you write your *application* according to the Java EE specification it will be able to be deployed and executed on any Java EE application server (of that level).

Note that the *configuration* is outside the specification.  This means that the configuration of the application server to provide the things your application needs, is non-standard and it may be a quite substantial effort for you to add support for a new application server.

Answer (score 1):

What Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen said is perfect. Also, the [Java EE 6 Technologies](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/index-jsp-142185.html) page lists the technologies included in Java EE 6 specification. You can consider any Application Server fully implementing these to be Java EE-Compliant.

Also the [Compatible Implementations](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/compatibility-jsp-136984.html) page lists the list of AS compatible to each Java EE version.